# Pointer and Array problem

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++, I'm having trouble with pointers etc. How can I fix the following problem?

*error: no match for 'operator=' in '*(stage->Stage::tiles + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)t) * 12u))) = (operator new(12u), (, ((Tile*))))'|
note: candidates are: Tile& Tile::operator=(const Tile&)|*

stage.h

```
#include "Tile.h"

class Stage {
    public:
        Tile *tiles;
        int size;
        void init(int size);
};
```

stage.cpp

```
void Stage::init(int size) {
    this->size = size;
    this->tiles = new Tile[size];
}
```

application.cpp

```
#include "Stage.h"
#include "Tile.h"

bool setTiles( Stage * stage ) {

    for( int t = 0; t < stage->size; t++ ) {
        stage->tiles[t] = new Tile();
    }

    return true;
}

stage.init(1234);
setTiles( &stage );
```

Also, I don't really know when to use `object.attribute` and when to use `object->attribute`?

Comment: `Stage` doesn't have a member variable called `size`.  Please post your *actual* code.

Comment: Sorry, I made this version particularly so that its easier to understand. Fixed it now.

Comment: Recovering Java programmer? If you just want `tiles` to be an array of tiles, you don't have to do anything beyond `new Tile[size]` -- that already invokes the default constructors for every element in the array. The entire `setTiles` function as you wrote it seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: **Please use `std::vector`!**  You will save yourself *a lot* of hassle!

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer- and if a dependency on Boost isn't an issue, take it a step further and use boost::ptr_vector.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer Could u give an example of using `std::vector` in this case?

Comment: @Kerrek SB That sounds awesome, however since I've now changed it to `this->tiles = new Tile*[total_tiles]` I guess it won't work anymore!? Also, I do need to pass some arguments to the constructor.

Comment: @Ben: could you please update your post accordingly, maybe add a new section? You cannot say `Tile * x = new Tile * [5];`, you would have to declare `Tile ** x;` or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

```
stage->tiles[t] = new Tile();
```

You're calling new on something that's not a pointer.  True, tiles is a pointer to an array, however, each element of that array is NOT a pointer.  In order for that work, you would need an array of pointers, or a pointer to a pointer ,such as:

```
Tile **tiles;
```

What you could also do is create a separate pointer object, allocate it, and then copy the data to your array element by using

```
stage->tiles[i] = *somePointer;
```

and then deleting the pointer afterwards to free that allocated memory.  This will preserve the copy because you invoked the copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to allocate a pointer with a pointer to an array. Try this one:

```
class Stage {
    public:
        Tile **tiles;
        void init(int size);
};
```

Comment: Where is he "trying to allocate a pointer with a pointer to an array"?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth This is actually pretty accurate (at least his fix is, his explanation isn't), read my answer. +1

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth:
`new Tile[size]` creates a pointer to an array of `Tile` with size `elements`
`Tile *tiles` is a array or a pointer to ONE `Tile`

Comment: @MGZero: Ok, but this answer is not complete (and neither is yours, actually).  The assignment in `init()` needs to become `this->tiles = new Tile*[size]`

Comment: He understands the problem and provides the solution, but his formulation is nonsense ;)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth you are right, i should stop hacking answers while i am on work, and do other things parallel ;)

Comment: @Thomas: The type of `new Tile[size]` is `Tile *`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth ok I'll agree with you on that :)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth isnt the type of `Tile[size]` already `Tile *` and `new` returns a pointer?

Comment: @Thomas: No.  `new Tile[size]` creates an array of `Tile`, and returns a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @Thomas Berger: `new Tile[size]` creates a `Tile*`, `new Tile*[size]` creates a `Tile**`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers/comments. I am using `Tile **tiles;` in stage.h, `this->tiles = new Tile*[total_tiles];` in Stage::init, and `stage->tiles[t] = new Tile( x, y, tileType );` in the application. This works and its great. However, I don't really understand why it works and  I keep running into problems of this or similar kind. Could you recommend any concise tutorials (as in *not* 600 page books...) particulalry about `&`, `*`, `.` or `->`, `**` and related (I'm coming from Java)? Also, could someone please show me how to deallocate all the things we've used here?

Comment: @Ben: C++ is *very* complex and as a beginner, there are many pitfalls, especially when using dynamic memory.  I would strongly recommend a good book; recommendations can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list .  For a basic tutorial, consider http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

```
stage->tiles[t] = new Tile();
```

The above is not a valid **C++** code, which you are perhaps confusing with the way new is used in other language such as **C#**. Though new can be used to allocate dynamic memories, but assigning an object to a particular element in the dynamically created array doesn't need  the `new` construct. In fact, the object is already created as soon as you called `new Tile[size]`. What you may want to do is, create an object of type `Tile` and assign it to a particular element in `tiles`.

```
Tile myTile;

// do something with myTile

this->tiles[0] = myTile;
```

Comment: Well, I need to call the constructor of `Tile` with some arguments, i.e. I need to do `Tile myTile = new Tile(...)` which won't work: error: conversion from 'Tile*' to non-scalar type 'Tile' requested --- coming from Java btw :)

Comment: @Ben: I understand you had background on C# or Java :). For your case, simply use this->titles[0] = Tile(...) ;)

Answer (score 0):

`new Tiles()`  returns a pointer to a Tiles instance.

`Tile *tiles`  defines an array out Tiles, not pointers.

Start with `Tile **tiles` instead.